# Is there a recommended time to pause before transmitting, after changing to a new frequency?

Tags: radio-communications

Does any aviation authority have a recommendation of ***how long to listen*** after changing to a new frequency before making a transmission?

[image]

[source](http://www.planetheadset.com/aviation-headset.php)

Comment: It depends upon the frequency. Normally you wait a few seconds on a non-busy frequency. On a class B approach frequency if you don't hear anything for a few seconds then you need to check your radio etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was always taught:

- Change frequency
- Give it a good 3 count
- If no one is talking, transmit

[The FAA just advises a pause as per the AIM [4-2-1]](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM_Basic_dtd_10-12-17.pdf) but gives no time specifically

> **a.** Listen before you transmit. Many times you can get the information
>   you want through ATIS or by monitoring the frequency. Except for a few
>   situations where some frequency overlap occurs, if you hear someone
>   else talking, the keying of your transmitter will be futile and you
>   will probably jam their receivers causing them to repeat their call.
>   If you have just changed frequencies, pause, listen, and make sure the
>   frequency is clear.

You will also learn to anticipate the flow. For example if you hear a controller issue something you should expect to hear the aircraft read it back. Once you get a feel for the cadence of chatter you will have even less issues.

Comment: If you're on an arrival to Chicago or NYC during rush hour, you might spend 30 secs just waiting for any dead space at all to chime in.

Answer (score 3):

My EASA compliant RT theory book states listen in for at least 5 seconds.

Whether that's a hard and fast regulation or a rule of thumb isn't stated, but the idea is you listen long enough to ensure nobody else is talking before opening your microphone.

Comment: Thx - I appreciate the intuitive logic and reference +1